# How to add a simple SVG path to a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to get a simple SVG graphic in my react app. But nothing is visible.

I created the graphic in Inkscape and got rid of (what I assumed was garbage ) extra code. Any help would be appreciated I'm a noob with SVGs

```
const test = () => {
    return (
        <svg viewBox="0 0 210 297">
            <path
                className="polymorph"
                d="m 0.22287672,94.082764 c 0,0 17.63282128,-34.831303 110.42670328,-36.348656 63.66595,-1.041057 101.55017,-59.333835 101.55017,-59.333835 L 211.66521,298.51041 H 0.75741577 Z"
            />
        </svg>
    );
};
```

I got it working. Apparently my problem was importing in camelCase instead of PascalCase.

```
import testSVG from '../src/components/test';

function App() {
    return <testSVG />;
}
```

```
import TestSVG from '../src/components/test';

function App() {
    return <TestSVG />;
}
```

[Screenshot of Chrome Browser not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdRxO.png)
[Screenshot of working SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCE2h.png)

Comment: Your code is working fine. What is the issue? Any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rendred element is,

```
<testsvg></testsvg>
```

it means youu have added your component like this,

```
<testsvg />
```

**When you add element using `lowercase` name, `React` thinks it is simple `HTML` tag and not a `React` component.**

Probably the issue with your Component name.

```
const test = () => {
```

You should use `PascalCase` name for your component, so your component should look like,

```
const Test = () => {   //Notice PacsalCase name
    return (
        <svg viewBox="0 0 210 297">
            <path
                className="polymorph"
                d="m 0.22287672,94.082764 c 0,0 17.63282128,-34.831303 110.42670328,-36.348656 63.66595,-1.041057 101.55017,-59.333835 101.55017,-59.333835 L 211.66521,298.51041 H 0.75741577 Z"
            />
        </svg>
    );
};

export default Test
```

Then you should import your component like this,

```
import Test from './Test'   //write correct filename
```

And finally usage,

```
<Test />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-239e6e)